# using Python reduce Count the number of occurrence of character in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find number of  "char " present in given string "string" using python reduce function?

i just learning about **reduce**. It will return only one element. so i am thinking there should be way to get this done using **reduce**.

Didn't find any so far.

Sample:

```
char:'s'
inputstring:'assntcs'

output(number of occurrence of s in 'assntcs'):-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **definitely** better ways to do this, but if you really want to use reduce you can use the following:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + (1 if y == 's' else 0), 'assntcs', 0)
3
```

This simply counts the elements in that string if they are the character you are looking for, in this case, `s`

Again, this is overly complicated.  You could simply use `count()`:

```
>>> 'assntcs'.count('s')
3
```

Comment: thank you..this is helpful. Just was learning the use of reduce.